# How can I create a plane using turtle and for statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, plane

My teacher would like me to use `turtle` to make a plane (graphing plane) with `for` statements. I can't figure it out so I was wondering if someone could provide the code for me.

```
#my start of code
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

Comment: Note that your teacher would like **you** to do it. There's literally no point to the exercise if someone else writes it for you. Please read http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: He refuses to teach us himself and tells us to use the internet even just a start would be amazing... I don't know how to move my starting point which I've been looking for if you could tell me how to do so

Comment: Then talk to the head of department or head teacher. This isn't a tutorial service. That said, have you considered actually reading the Python module documentation?

Comment: Done so already I couldn't get it my true problem is I can read code but I can't code myself

Comment: I guess you mean that you want to draw a grid. Do you know how to do `for` loops in Python? Have you had a look at the Python [Turtle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)?

Comment: Then maybe that isn't the course for you.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes I have I know a bit about for loops and jonrsharpe it really isn't I don't know why he's teaching us this I'm taking informational tech which I realize includes coding but we've been coding FOR 3 YEARS I WON'T EVER USE THE PROGRAMS HE'S TAUGHT US AND THEN WE HAVE TO SELF TEACH OURSELVES

Comment: You _might_ find [this tutorial](https://opentechschool.github.io/python-beginners/en/simple_drawing.html) helpful.

Comment: @PM2Ring I feel I want to blow up this school now they block anything that helps -_-

Comment: NYU has a few interesting [tutorials](http://python2013fall.globalblogs.org/category/turtle-graphics/) tutorials on using turtle. Also, I'd delete the threat, never know when something silly like that can come back and bite your rear end

Comment: Maybe that course isn't the course for _anyone_. Can you drop it, go teach yourself Python (with an online tutorial, or taking an outside course or something), then go back and re-take the class now that you understand more than the teacher? :)

Comment: I can't drop it because I goto a vocational Highschool and this is my last 4 weeks of the course so either way no point

Comment: Via this question, we are going to learn more about your life than you about Python  :)

Comment: Well, you can still take an intensive course that actually teaches you the basics of Python over the next week or so. That _might_ not help you get through the last three weeks of the class, but turning in answers to your homework that you don't understand is _definitely_ not going to help you…

Comment: @abarnert no one likes the teacher of the course because he was a math major who gives us videos from other people and doesn't know what he's talking about half the time... only reason he can teach this class is because he went to this school for electric

Comment: this isn't homework if it was I'd be able to see more and be able to know how to do this it's direct classwork and I've found no help on any of the unblocked sites which is when I turn to this site just saying this is my LAST choice of help

Comment: @FuriousFoxxy: Have you made any progress on this task? Or is it too late now?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will be helpful. It's hard to learn to program merely by reading code, you need to get experimental: pull it apart & put it back together again until you understand what all the different pieces are doing. So play with the code, and try modifying various things to see what happens.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Draw a squared grid filling the visible portion of the Turtle window
    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/29943686/4014959
    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.04.30
'''

import turtle

def draw_lines(current, num, length, delta):
    for i in range(num):
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(current)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.forward(length)
        current += delta

def draw_grid(step):
    cols = turtle.window_width() // step
    rows = turtle.window_height() // step
    mx, my = cols * step, rows * step
    origin = turtle.Vec2D(-mx // 2, -my // 2)

    #Horizontals
    delta = turtle.Vec2D(0, step)
    draw_lines(origin, rows + 1, mx, delta)

    #Verticals
    turtle.left(90)
    delta = turtle.Vec2D(step, 0)
    draw_lines(origin, cols + 1, my, delta)

def main():
    turtle.setup(width=0.8, height=0.8)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed(0)

    draw_grid(25)

    #Wait for the window to be closed
    turtle.done()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```